# React-Native Link app to Facebook Messenger

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking

I know I can deep link maps for example, I used it and it works fine. But how about FB Messenger? I have a button, that when user clicks I want it to open Messenger with a conversation with someone. How can I do it? I tried directly linking but it doesn't work.

```
  openMessenger() {
    Linking.canOpenURL('https://www.messenger.com/t/name').then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
            Linking.openURL('https://www.messenger.com/t/name');
        } else {
            console.log('erro');
        }
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
  }
```

also tried `fb-messenger://user-thread/{user-id}` and still didn't work.

btw, is there any way to ask the user which app he wants to open with? In the case of the maps, when I click the button it opens on Apple Maps on iOS, but I want it to ask which app to open instead, as I don't use Apple Maps for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, this library worked for me: 
https://github.com/fiber-god/react-native-app-link

Comment: can u please share how u got it worked? what is the playstore id?

Comment: id is on the link when you search for the app on playstore (id=com.facebook.orca). To make it work just follow the example on github repo, its pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

```
Linking.canOpenURL('fb-messenger://').then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {
       console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
    } else {
       Linking.openURL("fb-messenger://user-thread/" + "facebook id");
    }
}).catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

**iOS**

> As of iOS 9, your app needs to provide the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
>   key inside Info.plist or canOpenURL will always return false.

Set LSApplicationQueriesSchemes => Restart server

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>fb-messenger</string>
</array>
```

[image]

**Android**

> To support deep linking on Android, refer
>   http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#handling-intents

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still wondering this is a straightforward way just to messenger to the existing react native application without any packages

Linking.openURL(`http://m.me/<PAGE_NAME>`)

[Official Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links)

Comment: Do you know how to send a message along the way?